# How do I center an entry across columns in a pmatrix?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, matrices

I have a matrix of the form:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} \boldsymbol{\Phi}_{l,t}^F \\ \mathbf{0} & \phi^R_{l,t} \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I would like to align `$\Phi$` centrally in the top row. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\multicolumn{}{}{}` to get a value centered. The first argument is the total number of columns you want to merge (2 in your case). The second argument is the horizontal alignment (c in your case). The third argument is the value you want to center (`\Phi` in your case).

This gives you `\multicolumn{2}{c}{\boldsymbol{\Phi}_{l,t}^F}`.

In your matrix, this becomes:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
        \begin{pmatrix} 
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\boldsymbol{\Phi}_{l,t}^F} \\ 
            \mathbf{0} & \phi^R_{l,t} 
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since the `pmatrix` environment is set up to typeset its content without much whitespace, it may not be the most suitable environment for the application at hand. I suggest you use a plain and simple `array` environment. Incidentally, you may want to load the `bm` package and use `\bm` instead of `\boldsymbol`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\biggl(\begin{array}{cc}
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bm{\Phi}_{l,t}^F} \\[1ex]
   \bm{0} & \phi^R_{l,t} \\
\end{array}\biggr)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a nested `matrix`; in this case, adding a small vertical space between the rows seems better.

Using `bm` is recommended; when it's loaded, `\boldsymbol` becomes equivalent to `\bm`, but the latter command is easier to type.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
  \bm{\Phi}_{l,t}^F \\[1ex]
  \begin{matrix}
    \mathbf{0} & \phi^R_{l,t}
  \end{matrix}
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]